# Underlining text in navbar

Tags: html, css

I want to try and underline the text of a navbar but the underline animation doesn't work.

this is my css for the underlining

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #333; 
}
  
.navbar a {
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    color: #dd5527; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 14px 20px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.navbar a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #dd5527;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

this is my html for the navbar

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">About Us</a>
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Services</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `transform:scale(0)` to set the initial scale and then set `transform-origin:left;` to transform from left to right. then use the `transition:transform 350ms ease-in;` to get the transition animation and finally set the `transform:scale(1)` on `a:hover::after` to scale back to original size. I have also  set some styling for the **underline** and **a** tag. I would suggest you use `display:flex;` on navbar instead of `float:left` on **a** tag.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: #dd5527;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #dd5527;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 450ms ease-in;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.nav-link:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">About Us</a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Services</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is working: your element is just rendered at the wrong place. You need to:

- add `position: relative` to the `<a>` element, and
- use `0` or a positive pixel value for the pseudo-element's `bottom` property so that it is not cut-off by `overflow: hidden` set on the parent container

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  position: relative; /* Fix */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #dd5527;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #dd5527;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; /* Fix */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">About Us</a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Services</a>
</div>
```